# rank() and length() with missing values in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a percentile rank function in R, but I am running into trouble with the `rank()` and `length()` commands due to missing values in the vectors.

Here's the code I have:

```
percentile.rank <- function(x) rank(x) / length(x)
percentile_mathscore <- percentile.rank(mathscore)
```

This isn't giving me the answer I need, because the vector `x` contains a number of missing values, so the `length(x)` and `rank(x)` commands aren't returning relevant numbers.  Is there a way to get the ranks and the length ignoring the missing values?

I figured out one way to do it, but it's kinda by brute force:

```
percentile.rank2 <- function(x){
   x2 <- na.omit(x)
   return(rank(x, na.last = NA, ties.method = "random")/length(x2))
   rm(x2)
 }
percentile_mathscore2 <- percentile.rank2(mathscore)
```

The problem here is that I need the vector length for `percentile_mathscore2` to be the same as the vector length for `mathscore` (i.e., where there's an `NA` in `mathscore`, I want an `NA` in `percentile_mathscore`).

Comment: You don't need `rm` in the function. `x2` is only defined in the function environment.

Comment: I'm with @Roland. Also, does any code after `return()` even evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution

```
prank<-function(x){
  r<-rank(x)/sum(!is.na(x))
  r[is.na(x)]<-NA
  r
}
```

You can get it down to one line if you want like this:

```
prank<-function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),NA,rank(x)/sum(!is.na(x)))
```

The reason this works is that by default, `rank` ranks NA values in last place.  Here it is with some sample data

```
> set.seed(123)
> x<-sample(10)
> x[sample(10,2)]<-NA
> x
 [1]  3  8  4  7 NA  1 10  9  2 NA
> rank(x)
 [1]  3  6  4  5  9  1  8  7  2 10
> prank(x)
 [1] 0.375 0.750 0.500 0.625    NA 0.125 1.000 0.875 0.250    NA
```

Comment: FYI your function is the same as `ecdf(x)(x)`

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
percentile.rank <- function(x)
  (rank(x, na.last=NA) / length(na.omit(x)))[seq(x)]
```

#### Why this works:

When you index a vector by a value larger than its length, `R` returns `NA`s.
   This, incidentally, serves well to pad a shorter vector to be as long as a longer vector.

Comment: My impression was that the OP wanted the `NA`s of the output in the same places as the `NA`s of the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
mathscore <- c(64, 78, NA, 100, 87, 92, 87, NA, 94)

my.percentile.rank <- function(x){
    percentile.rank <-
        rank(x,na.last="keep",ties.method="random")/length(which(!is.na(x)))
    return(percentile.rank)
}

> my.percentile.rank(mathscore)
[1] 0.1428571 0.2857143        NA 1.0000000 0.5714286 0.7142857 0.4285714
[8]        NA 0.8571429
```

I would argue that this "percentile" is perhaps a bit misleading, however, as the NA values have effectively been removed from the population. For example, is the score of 64 really the "worst", given the two NA scores? Also the `"random"` treatment of ties that you specified is certainly misleading. Why should identical scores get different ranks? I would choose one of the other treatment options (`"average"`, `"min"` or `"max"`).